# Doctrine 2: fetch all records with or without match records in a one to many association in single table inheritance

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I am trying to find the total count of listings in each categories base on listing location

What I am trying to do is if a user from United States visits the site only records from that location are shown. Also the category widget on the sidebar should take into account the total number of listing under each category in that location. If the visitor clicks on Chicago, The widget should recalculate to reflect the location 'Chicago'

with the code below

```
    public function findCategoriesWithTotalListing($location)
{
    $builder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

    $builder->select('c, count(l.id) AS num')
       ->from('Bundle\AdvertBundle\Entity\Category', 'c')
       ->leftJoin('c.listings','l')
       ->leftJoin('l.country','co')
       ->leftJoin('l.state','st')
       ->leftJoin('l.city','ci');

    $builder->groupBy('c.id');

    $result = $builder->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    print_r($result);
    exit;
}
```

I am able to retrieve all categories with total count of each listing without the location param.

But if I introduce the location param, only those categories that have listings in that location are retrieved.

```
    public function findCategoriesWithTotalListing($location)
{
    $builder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

    $builder->select('c, count(l.id) AS num')
       ->from('Bundle\AdvertBundle\Entity\Category', 'c')
       ->leftJoin('c.listings','l')
       ->leftJoin('l.country','co')
       ->leftJoin('l.state','st')
       ->leftJoin('l.city','ci');

    $orx = $builder->expr()->orX();
    $orx->add($builder->expr()->like("co.slug", ':location'));
    $orx->add($builder->expr()->like("st.slug", ':location'));
    $orx->add($builder->expr()->like("ci.slug", ':location'));

    $builder->andWhere($orx);
    $builder->groupBy('c.id');
    $builder->setParameter('location',$location);

    $result = $builder->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    print_r($result);
    exit;
}
```

I want all categories

What am I possibly doing wrong here

Thanks

Entities below

Category Entity

```
<?php

namespace Bundle\AdvertBundle\Entity;

use Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Entity\BaseEntity;
use Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Entity\DocumentInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Category
*
* @ORM\Table(name="listings_categories")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Bundle\AdvertBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
*/
class Category extends BaseEntity implements DocumentInterface
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
private $slug;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="summary", type="text", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
private $summary;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="parent", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
private $parent;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ListingItem", mappedBy="category")
 */
private $listings;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="thumbnail", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
 */
private $thumbnail;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="form_template", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
 */
private $formTemplate;


private $children;


private $totalChildren;

private $totaListing;


/* Getters and Setters*/


}
```

Listing Entity

```
<?php
namespace Bundle\AdvertBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Entity\DocumentInterface;
use Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Entity\BaseEntity;


/**
* @ORM\Entity (repositoryClass="Bundle\AdvertBundle\Repository\ListingItemRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="listings")
* @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="listing_type", type="string")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 "forsale" = "ForsaleItem", 
  "service" = "ServiceItem",
 "job" = "JobItem",
 "realestate" = "RealEstateItem",
 "land" = "LandItem",
"house" = "HouseItem"
})
*/
abstract class ListingItem extends BaseEntity
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
protected $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
protected $slug;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", precision=0, scale=2, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
protected $price;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
protected $description;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="thumbnail", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
 */
protected $thumbnail;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=100, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
protected $status;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_created", type="datetime", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
 */
protected $dateCreated;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_approved", type="datetime", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
 */
protected $dateApproved;

/**
 * @var \Bundle\AdvertBundle\Entity\Category
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\AdvertBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="listings")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * })
 */
protected $category;

/**
 * @var \Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="listings")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * })
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
protected $email;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="contact_number", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
protected $contactNumber;

/**
 * @var \Bundle\LocationBundle\Entity\Country
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\LocationBundle\Entity\Country")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * })
 */
private $country;

/**
 * @var \Bundle\LocationBundle\Entity\State
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\LocationBundle\Entity\State")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="state_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * })
 */
private $state;

/**
 * @var \Bundle\LocationBundle\Entity\City
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\LocationBundle\Entity\City")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * })
 */
private $city;


protected $dateformat = 'd-M-Y';

}
```

Location Entity

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity (repositoryClass="Bundle\LocationBundle\Repository\LocationRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="locations")
* @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="location_type", type="string")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
"country" = "Country", 
"state" = "State",
"city" = "City"
})
*/
abstract class Location
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country_code", type="string", length=3, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
 */
protected $countryCode;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
protected $slug;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="geoname_id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
protected $geonameId;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lng", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */

protected $lng;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lat", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
protected $lat;


/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bundle\LocationBundle\Entity\Location", mappedBy="parent")
 */
protected $children;

/**
 * @var \Bundle\LocationBundle\Entity\Location
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\LocationBundle\Entity\Location", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * })
 */
protected $parent;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="currency_symbol", type="string", length=100, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
 */
protected $currencySymbol;

/* getters and setters*/
}
```

Country Entity

```
namespace Bundle\LocationBundle\Entity;

use Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Entity\DocumentInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Country
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="locations")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Bundle\LocationBundle\Repository\LocationRepository")
 */
class Country extends Location
{

/**
 * Set countryCode
 *
 * @param string $countryCode
 * @return Country
 */
public function setCountryCode($countryCode)
{
    $this->countryCode = $countryCode;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get countryCode
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCountryCode()
{
    return $this->countryCode;
}
}
```

State and city entites are just like the country

Comment: If you want count item in each category in one query, I think you must use subquery. Now  you count items that have same location in all categories. Or you can just make 3 separate query, that count item in each category.

Comment: Yes I want count of all items that are under each category from the visitor current location

Comment: So I think you need subquery, or 3 separate query.

Answer (score 0):

With your WHERE you are filtering out all those not matching categories so it can't count them. It should be possible to do by one query, but you have to move conditions from WHERE to get even not-matching rows and count them as 0.
[Simple SQL version:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/535f48/10)

```
SELECT c.*, sum(IF(loc.code = 'x', 1, 0))
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN list l ON c.id = l.c_id
LEFT JOIN loc ON loc.id = l.loc_id
GROUP BY c.id
```

In Doctrine there is no IF, but you can use

```
CASE WHEN (<cond>) THEN 1 ELSE 0
```

as  you use $orx expr.

Another posibility is moving conditions to those joins like in [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/535f48/14) but then you have to do arbitrary join in doctrine to specify custom ON:

> from documentation: Arbitrary JOIN Syntax (FROM User u JOIN Comment c WITH c.user = u.id)
>   then you will sum three counts for those three joined tables. It's doable but ugly.

Or subqueries as stated by @denys281 - select only from categories but select clause contains column which counts all matching listings for each category.

Answer (score 0):

After several days of looking into subqueries in doctrine I finally got the code that works for my situation.
Here are some few pionts that got me to rethink about how I wrote the first code.

1. I needed all categories.
2. I needed a count of all listings in each category
3. Select only those listing that are related to the location parameter passed in.
4. Listings have a many to one associating with location.

The obvious solution is to use subquery as suggested by @danys281.

```
    public function findCategoriesWithTotalListing($location)
{
    $subQuery = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $subQuery->select('COUNT(l.id)')
             ->from('Bundle\AdvertBundle\Entity\ListingItem','l')
             ->leftJoin('l.category','cat')
             ->leftJoin('l.country','co')
             ->leftJoin('l.state','st')
             ->leftJoin('l.city','ci')
             ->where('cat.id = c.id');  

    if($location instanceOf Country){
        $subQuery->andWhere('co.slug = :location');
    }

    if($location instanceOf State){
        $subQuery->andWhere('st.slug = :location');    
    }

    if($location instanceOf City){
        $subQuery->andWhere('ci.slug = :location');
    }

    $subQuery->andWhere("l.status = :status");


    $builder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $builder->select("c, (".$subQuery->getDql().") AS num")
       ->from('Bundle\AdvertBundle\Entity\Category', 'c')
       ->setParameters(['location'=>$location->getSlug(),'status'=>'active'])
       ->groupBy('c');

    return $builder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Thank you all for given me the hint.